# Failed to return the width() of element when using jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

**Demo page for testing**: http://jsfiddle.net/rCKzs/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        alert( $("#test").width() );          
    });
</script>

..

<div id="test">content</div>
```

If I remove the jQuery Mobile, then it is okay, otherwise it return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use document.ready with jQM:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

> **Important: Use pageInit(), not $(document).ready()**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   `$(document).ready()` function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Also jQM only supports jQuery 1.6.4

I would use the live() like this

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    alert($("#test").width());  
});
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/rCKzs/1/

Comment: For my specific issue when binding to pageinit my div still gave a height of 0, but binding to `.live('pageshow',...` (as suggested) worked great.